# Use predefined variable in function

Tags: bash, function, variables, arguments

Could be possible to use predefined variable after function is executed.
Ex.:

```
var="host1 host2"
function test {
echo $1
echo $2
}
test var host3
```

Expected result should to be:

```
host1 host2 
host3
```

Not sure how use define that variable like local or something else ...

Comment: `test "$var" host3` ??

Answer (score 3):

You can have this code in your function with indirect variable reference

```
testfn() {
   for v; do
      echo "${!v:-$v}"
   done
}

var="host1 host2"
```

then call it as:

```
testfn var host3
```

which will print this output:

```
host1 host2
host3
```

Expression `"${!v:-$v}"` attempts to reference a variable with the string contained in `$v` and if it is not set then used `$v` (which is positional argument string).

Comment: Probably you are right. I posted it in case OP wants it the way it is shown in question.

Comment: I just deleted my answer to make this de-facto!

Comment: @Inian No you should keep your answer as that is simple and it might resolve OP's problem.

Comment: Nah! this is more comprehensive, just do an edit of yours with that!